# How to reference SSRS report parameter by name

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, reportviewer, reportparameter

I have the following code that I'm attempting to programmatically create an xml report with through ReportViewer.

```
Dim outputPath As String = "C:\backup\test.xml"
Dim reportViewer As New ReportViewer()
Dim serverReport As ServerReport = reportViewer.ServerReport()

reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/<path>/<report>"
reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("http://<ip>/reportserver")
reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local

reportViewer.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("<user>", "<pwd>")

Dim parameters As New List(Of ReportParameter)

parameters.Add(New ReportParameter("LocationLocationParent", "[Location].[Location Parent].&[2]"))
parameters.Add(New ReportParameter("CalendarYear", "[Calendar].[Year].&[2014-01-01T00:00:00]"))
parameters.Add(New ReportParameter("StaffStaffName", "[Staff].[Staff Name].&[Bob Smith]"))

Try
    serverReport.SetParameters(parameters)

    Dim mimeType As String = ""
    Dim encoding As String = ""
    Dim extension As String = ""
    Dim streams As String() = Nothing
    Dim warnings As Warning() = Nothing

    Dim xmlBytes As Byte() = serverReport.Render("XML", String.Empty, mimeType, encoding, extension, streams, warnings)

    Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create)
        fs.Write(xmlBytes, 0, xmlBytes.Length)
        fs.Close()
    End Using

Catch reportEx As ReportServerException
    Debug.Print(reportEx.Message)
End Try
```

where I'm setting the parameter for LocationLocationParent, it is not allowing me to set the value by name, only by some type of index each value in the list has.  The drop down list on the SSRS report itself is in a tree-like structure, something like this:

```
Parent1
    Parent2
        Parent4
            Child1
            Child2
        Parent5
            Child3
            Child4
        Child5
    Parent3
        Child5
        Child6
```

This list is not a true tree but just viewed like one.  It is a multi-select list of checkbox items.  I cannot set the parameter to value "Child3" for example - only by its index, but there are 100s of values in the list on the Report Window.  If I set it like this:
"[Location].[Location Parent].&[Child3]" I get the following exception

This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report parameter 'LocationLocationParent'. To run or subscribe to this report, you must provide a parameter value. (rsReportParameterValueNotSet)

Note that the StaffStaffName parameter is not formed in a tree-like structure, just a list, so I am able to set that parameter correctly.

How can I set to the name of the value I want for LocationLocationParent?

Comment: How is the tree drop down generated? In SSRS? There is nothing native like that in SSRS.

Comment: From what I was told, it was native to SSRS.  But I did forget to mention a detail.  It's not a true tree, just appears to be like one, with indentations.  It is a tree-like multi-select drop down list of checkboxes.

Comment: If it's just a standard combo box (with indentations) then you need to find the query that populates it. It will be a standard code/description type, and you just need to pass the code.

Comment: Thanks, @Nick.McDermaid.  Now that list will be dynamic...so does that mean whenever that list changes, I'll have to get the new list of code/description types so that I'll know what to pass in?  If that's my only option, I can try to find out.  I'm sort of at the mercy of however that list gets filled every time unless there is a way to pass in the name rather than code.

Comment: How are you getting the existing list of location names? Are they hard coded? Anyway until we know how the combo is populated we're just guessing. You'll need to find out the query that populates it and we can go from there. Is this the only drop down on the report?